# 32 bit mongo db is not starting because of exceeding size(2gb)

Tags: mongodb

I am using `32 bit` windows machine and using `32 bit` mongodb. I noticed my database is not starting and it says

```
 ** WARNING: This 32-bit MongoDB binary is deprecated
2016-01-03T16:53:03.720+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-01-03T16:53:03.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-01-03T16:53:03.732+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
2016-01-03T16:53:03.740+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
2016-01-03T16:53:03.754+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
2016-01-03T16:53:03.761+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
2016-01-03T16:53:03.771+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

My database size is 2.03gb. Now, I want to delete some unnecessary collections.

But without even starting the `mongoDB` server how can I delete some collections?

Comment: You can try to delete the collection using cmd. I doubt it'll work when the database isn't on, but you can try: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/drop/

Comment: Have you tried `--journal`?

Comment: I wrote the command mongod.exe --journal but not working

Comment: if the server is not starting then you can't do anything, you might want to check the folder where mongo store data and try your luck to backup and delete some collection data file

Comment: How many databases do you have? Example: You can move temporally `admin.*` files, `admin` folder and try to start...

Answer (score 0):

in 32-bit version of mongodb there is a limit of file size with 2gb , tou can try --smallfiles in mongod which will create a 512mb data files rather 2 gb, and more over it is a warning.

thanks,
Darshan J